# How is Share Count in Facebook Open Graph Calculated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-analytics

Something a bit strange is going on. My page has 1,828 unique page views in Google Analytics. It is showing 7 Facebook shares through Google's Social Interaction Tracking. The tracking code is fired as a part of a callback from Facebook to indicate a successful share post. And, when I go to Facebook Graph API, it is showing share_count = 546.

I tracked down an article from Mashable that said the following about their own Facebook share buttons:

*"Any share that is done either via the MashShare Share button or internally via the sharing function on a facebook post for the same url is counted as one separate share. Beside of that every extra comment made on the internal facebook post increments the share counter as well when the comment is made within the timeline of the commenting user. Additionally we noticed that likes of a post are also taken into account."*

Has anyone else been able to verify this? Wondering if this is truly the reason for the massive differences between the share count Google Analytics is registering and the share count from the Facebook Graph API.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_511735725680961

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks for the link!